# Parsing a text file containing XML tags into an array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, parsing

I need to parse a text file that includes html tags like this:

```
<item>
 <value4="L5u9eDNV40_val4">
 <value6="xcE90l2HyN_val6">
 <value3="hJyVXoE4YQ_val3">
 <value5="K68yGpDsTR_val5">
 <value2="umrVvR8Tfe_val2">
 <value1="y6Ms2E5BHe_val1">
</item>

<item>
 <value4="T4PFOipm3u_val4">
 <value2="upLkW2r8nq_val2">
 <value3="3h7lV6CaHP_val3">
 <value5="4pETv3bt5c_val5">
 <value1="iEPZCnzxjs_val1">
 <value6="fWjg1Ueo5M_val6">
</item>
```

I need to use PHP, and the result should be in an array like this:

```
array (size=10000) 
0 => array (size = 3) 
'value1' => string 'L5u9eDNV40_val4',
'value2' => string 'umrVvR8Tfe_val2',
'value4' => string 'T4PFOipm3u_val4'    `
```

I have tried this using SimpleHTMLDOM but I can't do anything that works.

Comment: You should be using an XML (not HTML) parser like SimpleXML or DOM, but this isn't even valid XML. Have you omitted some of the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what final data structure you want, but this code will create an array of arrays, `$v_arr`, where each of the sub-arrays contains the values for one `<item>`:

```
$v_arr = array();
# split the string up into an array with one <item> per array element
$items = explode("<item>", $text);
foreach ($items as $i) {
    # only parse entries that have <value... tags
    if (strpos($i, '<value') !== false) {
        # parse the value tags, save the matches in $matches
        if (preg_match_all('#<(value\d)="(.+?)">#', $i, $matches)) {
            # create a new array with valueX as keys, the other string as values.
            # push this array on to a results array
            $v_arr[] = array_combine( $matches[1], $matches[2] );
        }
    }
}
print_r($v_arr);
```

Output for the text you posted:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value4] => L5u9eDNV40_val4
            [value6] => xcE90l2HyN_val6
            [value3] => hJyVXoE4YQ_val3
            [value5] => K68yGpDsTR_val5
            [value2] => umrVvR8Tfe_val2
            [value1] => y6Ms2E5BHe_val1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value4] => T4PFOipm3u_val4
            [value2] => upLkW2r8nq_val2
            [value3] => 3h7lV6CaHP_val3
            [value5] => 4pETv3bt5c_val5
            [value1] => iEPZCnzxjs_val1
            [value6] => fWjg1Ueo5M_val6
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<(value\d+)="([^"]*)"
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lD8uH4/3

Comment: Thank you, it very helps me, but I can't understand how to put "value1","value2" in the array-key notation? Like this ['value2'] => 'T4PFOipm3u_val4'

Comment: @Nevada use this.Grab the matches.Match one will be key to your dictionaryand match2 will be its vlaue

Comment: `<?php

$filename = "parsing.txt";

//  '/<value\d+="([^"]*)"/' 

$html = file_get_contents($filename);

preg_match_all('/<value\d+/', $html, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
//var_dump($matches);
for ($i=0; $i < count($matches); $i++) {
  

}

preg_match_all('/"([^"]*)"/', $html, $matches2, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

for ($i=0; $i < count($matches2); $i++) {
  

}

$arr = array_merge($matches, $matches2);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);

?>`

Comment: @Nevada you need to ue something like match.groups(1) and match.groups(2) something like this.